Port is already in use
I was working on a Node.js application. During development, it was running on the local server. Whenever I made changes to the application and tried to run it again, it would not run on the specified port number. Each time, I had to change the port number, even after a minor modification. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

How are you running the server? Need more info.

have you stopped the previously running "server"?

If you don't shutdown the server properly before running again, that's what you get.
